# Is there a better pathfinding algorithm than A* when you have multiple sources and multiple destinations?

Tags: java, graph, path-finding

We have a school project where we have an 8x8 game board with pieces on it. The goal is to get any piece to any square of the opposite back row. The pieces can only move forward, but in any forward direction (forward-left, forward or forward-right).

We were able to represent the board as a directed acyclic graph, and with the various rules of the game we were also able to set a weight on every edge. In short, we are pathfinding, with every piece as possible origin, to any of the back row squares, in order to find the path of least resistance from any piece to finish. Besides, *most* resistance will be met near the finish line.

However, our program spends a lot of time doing just that. We believe this is because a lot of paths are extremely similar in weight, especially given that any possible step will lead towards victory (since it's only possible to move forward and all back row squares are destinations). There are no obstacles on this board, just edges that weight heavier, so this leaves us with a lot of open nodes that all 'look good'.

Our heuristic function is very simple:

```
movement_cost = # movement cost here #
def heuristic(node):
    return node.cost + node.distanceToFinish * movement_cost
```

Where `node.cost` is the sum of the weights of the traversed edges, plus `movement_cost` times the number of traversed edges.

Is there an algorithm that will be more efficient than A* to handle cases where you have multiple origins and multiple destinations? The board is never going to be bigger than 8x8 either, so space-hungry algorithms are probably welcome, too.

**EDIT** We thought about pathfinding from finish to the pieces, but this adds a good deal of complexity to the heuristic function, since we now have to keep track of every piece rather than just track of how far we are from the last line.

Comment: I'm interested in doing something similar. Specifically, I'm interested in finding a path that includes a specific point in it - for example, finding directions to a destination that also includes a stop at a gas station. Do you know if it's possible to adapt A* to do that?

Comment: @EJoshuaS, sounds like you're trying to solve some version of the traveling salesman problem.

Comment: Good point - it does seem slightly more constrained than the "classic" traveling salesman problem that I remember from undergraduate AI class because you have to visit the points in a specific order (if I'm remembering correctly, the original version only requires that you end up back where you started), but that's still a legitimate variant of that. Would that imply that A* is a poor choice, then? Do I still need to treat this as a TSP variant if there are only two points?

Comment: @EJoshuaS, if you know exactly where you're going and in which order you're visiting points, the optimal path is just the combination of the optimal paths from one point to the next. If you have multiple choices, then I don't really know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the size of the problem makes it so the "brute force" approach is the most efficient–that is, computing the shortest path to every node from every source by traversing the whole grid is faster than employing A*. This is likely because we don't have any of the overhead incurred by the `PriorityQueue` and comparisons can be made simpler.

This probably wouldn't be a good idea for larger sizes though, since this is O(n<sup>2</sup>) with the width of the grid.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a specific suboptimization of the problem in mind, A* is entirely appropriate for your purposes. However, you can improve this solution through [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) of paths shared amongst pieces, allowing you to calculate the cost of each path to the target a minimum number of times.

Comment: We don't reopen nodes when we find another path to them, so we should already have the benefits memoization describes.

Answer (score -1):

[Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is a pathfinding algorithm that finds the least-cost path from a given node to every other node in the graph. You may want to take a look at this, and see if it's more efficient for your use case.